# Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Can anyone help me sort out this error please? my code doesn't want to be inherited as you can see in the error. the name space im using is WebChat which im using in both files so I don't really know where the error is.

```
userchathomepage.aspx:

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="userchathomepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="userchathomepage" %>

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebChat
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for userchathomepage.
    /// </summary>
    public class userchathomepage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

class fie : Chat.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;

namespace WebChat.PageModule
{/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Chat
/// </summary>
public class Chat
{
```

Comment: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="userchathomepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebChat._userchathomepage" %>

Answer (score 0):

The underline before the name of the class

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="userchathomepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebChat._userchathomepage" %>
```

Comment: Sorry but i didn't understand what u mean?

Comment: I added the class from where I'm trying to inherit called Chat. other codes are already there the userchathomepage.aspx and userchathomepage.aspx.cs. I dont think I need to put all the codes because it won't help.

Comment: I mean you have `Inherits="WebChat.userchathomepage"` on your aspx, so your class in the .aspx.cs called `_userchathomepage`

Comment: I changed that one but the error still there!I though the same and I even changed the namespace as in my class WebChat.PageModule but still getting same error

Comment: It will not compile without the namespace preceding the class name.

Comment: I'm sorry sure you should include the namespace. I'm just telling: fix your class name in the `aspx` file

Answer (score 0):

The class name is wrong in your question:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="userchathomepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebChat._userchathomepage" %>
```

Also keep the namespace `WebChat` if the class is inside.

Comment: For which form is not working? According to your question, this should fix it.

Comment: I even removed the chat class from the code folder for avoiding any coinfusin, and removed the _ before userchathomepage.cs so my code now that im using is like this <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="userchathomepage.aspx.cs" Inherits="userchathomepage" %>

Comment: Did you removed the namespace also from the class behind?

Comment: No i didnt,how can i inherit if i Removed the namepace?

Comment: You can inherit without namespace, I did not said to remove it. You should put it like this Inherits="WebChat.userchathomepage", otherwise it will still complain that cannot found the class...